# Adding ViewCell Disclosure Indicator Accessory to Xamarin.Forms Android and Iphone

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, renderer

I found a lots of Mobile Apps (Android & IOS) having a listview with icon on the most right side such as disclosure, checkmark & etc. That's call viewcell renderer. 
I know how to make it to the iphone, but I've no idea how to make it to android? 
Appreciate someone can share with me how to apply it to android. Thanks in advance.
you may see the image i uploaded below:
[image]
[image]

I add a class file in iOS, code as below:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using CustomRenderer.iOS;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), 
typeof(StandardViewCellRenderer))]
namespace CustomRenderer.iOS
{
class StandardViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    public override UIKit.UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, 
UIKit.UITableViewCell reusableCell, UIKit.UITableView tv)
    {
        var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
        switch (item.StyleId)
        {
            case "none":
                cell.Accessory = UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.None;
                break;
            case "checkmark":
                cell.Accessory = 
UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.Checkmark;
                break;
            case "detail-button":
                cell.Accessory = 
UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailButton;
                break;
            case "detail-disclosure-button":
                cell.Accessory = 
UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DetailDisclosureButton;
                break;
            case "disclosure":
            default:
                cell.Accessory = 
UIKit.UITableViewCellAccessory.DisclosureIndicator;
                break;
        }
        return cell;
    }

 }
}

Then, in my main XAML, code as below:
<ListView x:Name="MyListView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell StyleId="detail-disclosure-button">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label Text="{Binding AnimalName}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
  </ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you will need to download an Image, (there is no truly native way of doing that, since it is an iOS design feature).

First download the respective icon (for example from [here](https://material.io/resources/icons/?icon=keyboard_arrow_right&style=baseline))

And then, use a Custom Renderer

using Android.Graphics;
using Android.Graphics.Drawables;
using Android.Views;
using Testapp.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ViewCell), typeof(CustomViewCellRenderer))]
namespace Testapp.Droid
{
    public class CustomViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {

        protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, Android.Views.ViewGroup parent, Android.Content.Context context)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCellCore(item, convertView, parent, context);

            //switch (item.StyleId)
            //{
            //  case "disclosure":

            //      break;
            //}



            var bmp = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(cell.Resources, Resource.Drawable.arrow);
            var bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(cell.Resources, Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(bmp, 50, 50, true));
            bitmapDrawable.Gravity = GravityFlags.Right | GravityFlags.CenterVertical;
            cell.SetBackground(bitmapDrawable);


            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

And then, this XAML:

```
<ListView>
                <ListView.ItemsSource>
                  <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>mono</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodroid</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotouch</x:String>
                    <x:String>monorail</x:String>
                    <x:String>monodevelop</x:String>
                    <x:String>monotone</x:String>
                    <x:String>monopoly</x:String>
                    <x:String>monomodal</x:String>
                    <x:String>mononucleosis</x:String>
                  </x:Array>
                  </ListView.ItemsSource>
                  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                     <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <StackLayout>
                                <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="#f35e20" />                             
                            </StackLayout>                           
                        </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

Which results in this:

[image: SampleApp]

Comment: I saw this way before in stackoverlow. So, really no other way to have such result for android ?

Comment: Either this, or do it in XAML. There is no other way.

Comment: Hi sir, I dont understand about your code:
 //switch (item.StyleId)
            //{
            //  case "disclosure":

            //      break;
            //}
may i have the complete code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do that in Android, I make a sample, you could download from ViewCell_Custom_Renderer folder of the GitHub for reference.

https://github.com/WendyZang/Test.git

For this sample, you need to create a Custom Cell first.

```
public class NativeCell : ViewCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty NameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Name", typeof(string), typeof(NativeCell), "");

    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty CategoryProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Category", typeof(string), typeof(NativeCell), "");

    public string Category
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CategoryProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CategoryProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ImageFilenameProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("ImageFilename", typeof(string), typeof(NativeCell), "");

    public string ImageFilename
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ImageFilenameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageFilenameProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And then create a custom Renderer on Android.

```
   [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(NativeCell),       typeof(NativeAndroidCellRenderer))]
 namespace CustomRenderer.Droid
{
public class NativeAndroidCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
{
    NativeAndroidCell cell;

    protected override Android.Views.View GetCellCore(Cell item, Android.Views.View convertView, ViewGroup parent, Context context)
    {
        var nativeCell = (NativeCell)item;
        Console.WriteLine("\t\t" + nativeCell.Name);

        cell = convertView as NativeAndroidCell;
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new NativeAndroidCell(context, nativeCell);
        }
        else
        {
            cell.NativeCell.PropertyChanged -= OnNativeCellPropertyChanged;
        }

        nativeCell.PropertyChanged += OnNativeCellPropertyChanged;

        cell.UpdateCell(nativeCell);
        return cell;
    }

    void OnNativeCellPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var nativeCell = (NativeCell)sender;
        if (e.PropertyName == NativeCell.NameProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            cell.HeadingTextView.Text = nativeCell.Name;
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == NativeCell.CategoryProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            cell.SubheadingTextView.Text = nativeCell.Category;
        }
        else if (e.PropertyName == NativeCell.ImageFilenameProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            cell.SetImage(nativeCell.ImageFilename);
        }
    }
}
}
```

[image]